# Python keep asking for raw_input in "while True"

Tags: python

I need python to keep asking the raw_input if the answer is different from 1 or 2.

Here the example:

```
print """What do you want me to do?

1) Press 1 if you want to .....
2) Press 2 if you want to ....."""

while True:
    answer1 = raw_input(" => ")

    if (answer1 == 1):
        ....
        ....

    elif (answer1 == 2):
        ....
        ....

    elif (answer1 != 1 or 2) or answer1.isalpha():
        print "I need 1 or 2"
```

The problem is that python is keeping asking the raw_input also if the user enter 1 or 2. 
Where am I wrong?

Comment: put a `break` in both the conditions when `answer == 1` and `answer == 2` in the end

Comment: Your base condition `while True:` will never gets false so it will go in infinite loop. You should use the boolean `True` in some variable and make it false when your conditions gets `True`.

Comment: set `answer1 = None` before the while loop and then the while loop should be `while answer1 != 1 and answer1 != 2:`.

Comment: The duplicate does not address the `or` problem in this question. There are better duplicate targets.

Answer (score 0):

You should put a `break` statement in the `if` and `elif` block if answer is `1` or `2` to break out of the while loop.

Example -

```
if (answer1 == 1):
    ....
    ....
    break
elif (answer1 == 2):
    ....
    ....
    break
```